# Is it bad to Pass "this" as an argument to a different class method in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, javascript-objects

I Wanted to know if this suggested approach to minimize the number of arguments in a function call.

In ReactJS, we have a component to make a service call, we wrote a service class.

To reduce the number of arguments, we are passing `this` as an argument and destructuring it at method call. Is this a suggested pattern?

```
export class SomeComponent extends Component {
    sendData() {
        //passing entire scop this as argument. 
        MainService.getData(ID, payload, this)
    }

    async successResponseHandler() {
        return true;
    }

    failureResponseHandler(error) {
        return false;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={ sendDate() }></button>
        );
    }
}

class MainService extends BaseService {
    getData(ID, payload, { responseHandler, errorHandler }) {
        return ClaimsApi
            .newClaimContact(URL, ID, payload)
            .then(responseHandler)
            .catch(errorHandler);
    }
}
```

Comment: In JavaScript you can use function.call(this,...)

Comment: Notice that the methods might expect to be called on the object they were destructured from, not being called like plain functions. You might need to `bind` them (before the destructuring).

Comment: No, this is not a good solution. To minimise the number of arguments, you should completely omit those handler callback arguments, and simply return the promise. Then do the promise chaining at the call site yourself: `sendData() {
        MainService.getData(ID, payload).then(() => true, () => false);
 }`

Comment: Why not have the success and failure callbacks inside the `MainService` class where it looks like they should belong?

Comment: I think having success and failure callback inside the MainServie class is best approach for this case.

Comment: @bergi : why we should not pass "this" as argument? any technical reason for this?

Comment: @B.V.SBharatKumar There is no problem with passing `this`, there are cases where it's totally appropriate. There is a problem with passing success and failure callbacks to a method that could/should just return a promise.